# imagemagick unable to load remote images

Tags: php, linux, file

I have a php script, which downloads, rescales and stores an image using the following command:

```
exec('convert -sample 100x100 http://someurl.com/pic.jpg images/somename.jpg');
```

It all worked fine until I put it on a different server (this one's gentoo, if that makes any difference. Apparently convert won't grab remote images, and if I feed it a url like above it returns
`convert: missing an image filename 'images/somename.jpg' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2822.`

I checked the use flags but nothing seems to relate to remote images...The new server is a local machine which I have root access to, so I can pretty much do whatever on it - so how can I make this work?

Another possibly related issue is that php's file_get_contents() won't get remote files from there either. Maybe it's a system-wide setting somewhere preventing binaries from getting remote files? Has anyone had an issue like this before? How did you solve it?

Thanks,
Mala

**Update: To clarify**
This problem (imagemagick) has nothing to do with PHP. It's on my laptop which can access the internet just fine, and is not related to firewalls. If I open up a shell and type
`convert -sample 100x100 http://someurl.com/pic.jpg images/somename.jpg`
it fails with the above error without even trying to access the internet. 'wget' on the other hand, as well as web-browsers etc work just fine. On other systems, the convert command when typed into a shell works with no errors.

*Please disregard the file_get_contents problem as I believe it is not related for the reasons above*

Comment: While I could solve the problem by making it a two-step wget -> convert process, I want to avoid this: I don't want to have to deal with timing issues and making shell scripts, etc. Imagemagick can load remote images, so I want to use this functionality instead of just hacking around the problem.

Comment: You need to recompile ImageMagick (first) and PHP (last). I don't speak Gentoo so I don't know the proper incantations, but I'd start looking in the build configuration files for options.

Comment: 'convert' still fails to get the file when called from the shell, so I don't think it has anything to do with php... None of the build options in ImageMagick seem to have anything to do with remote files :-\

Comment: Does the remote server "see" the internet? Try pinging some webpage from the console of your server

Comment: The issue isn't on the remote machine but on the local one (i.e. I'm mirroring the website on my laptop). It sees the internet just fine (i'm on it right now) but imagemagick doesn't seem to want to parse urls for some reason...

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your copy of imagemagick. I would suggest seeing if there is a later version available or recompiling the existing.

Comment: Another thing you should try is install wireshark watch the network traffic and see if the answer can be found there. try it with file_get_contents() as well. It should be revealing. If there is no network activity for either then a system library may be at fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather unintuitively, imagemagick must be compiled **with the xml support** in order to load remote images. Thus, Gentoo users will need to enable the **xml** useflag.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is a permission problem. 
Check the permissions on the target directory. make sure imagemagick can actually save files there.

Remember that PHP run from the http server runs with different permissions than running from the commandline.

DC

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to retrieve other resources via HTTP?

If not then the server likely has a firewall enabled which is preventing access (as you mentioned PHP file_get_contents() function fails also).

If you are able to retrieve other resources via HTTP then the server you're attempting to grab the image from could be blocking you access for some reason.

Its also important to note that any calls to exec will run the program as the same user as PHP, so make sure the user PHP runs as does not have any permission issues.

Comment: Thanks for your input =) The problem in question (convert) isn't related to PHP, nor am I behind draconian firewalls that prevent HTTP requests (please see my update). Any other ideas?