# Imagemagick - for conversion of url images (image from amazon s3)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have problem with conversion using imagemagick.

I installed imagemagick successfully and i tried converting static(local)images using imagemagick and it is working fine.

```
 Syntax followed : convert logo : static.jpeg
```

The above one is working for other extensions png  etc...

Then i tried to give url of my image from s3 for conversion , but i got an error as mentioned below.

```
 Syntax followed: convert logo: static.xyz.com/id/image/abcd.jpg
```

### Error obtained

```
convert.exe: unable to open image `static.xyz.com/id/image
/abcd.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.
c/OpenBlob/2647.
```

Before this testing in command prompt , i tried the same dynamically in my code logic as below.

```
      im.resize({
              srcPath:'static.xyz.com/id/image/abcd.jpg',
                    width: 100,
                }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                           thumb = stdout;
                    console.log({thumb: thumb});
                });// successful response
```

But this doesn't work. ie unable to open the image.

Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this Question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018855/imagemagick-unable-to-load-remote-images

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use pretty npm for it. It name is easyimage.

npm install easyimage

And my re-size looks like:

```
  easyimg.resize({
      src: pathTpImage,
      dst: destination,
      width: 50,
      height: 50
    }, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err, null);
      }

      return next(null, 1);
    });
});
```

If you want to get image from some url you can use native package require('http') and next you will be able to do some stuff with image.

Comment: Hai Thanks  to  all for quick reply.but i want to resize image pass to view page ,i dont want to store designation path.how can i do it thia way in easyimage.please help.

Comment: if you add links to the documentation your post will be more useful ;)

Comment: i have mentioned my requirement in my question, there is no specific documentation for this requirement. Actually my requirement is At the time of displaying images , i have to resize it and display. I dont want that image to be stored in some path . Original file is stored in s3 , resized image need not be stored again. It is just for display purpose. Thanks

Comment: hai,I added one more option for strip : false in im,resize.currently i have the diffrent error.    { [Error: Command failed: convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format
`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert.exe: no images defined `jpg:-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/316
1.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
{ stdout: '' } ,please any one suggest to me.how can i fix this error.Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to crop image without storing to file system, but it was not done. In easyimage doc was written that I could crop or resize image with helping CLI. But I could`t do this. So now I am using approach with storing images to FS. If you find solution for it please let me know.